# safari plugin crashing on NP_Initialize when built on xulrunner sdk

Tags: macos, plugins, safari, webkit, npapi

I am trying to build NPAPI plugin for safari and have been trying to run the simple NPAPI plugin example from https://github.com/mikma/npsimple on Safari on Mac.
The plugin can use npapi library from WEBKIT_DARWIN_SDK or from XULRUNNER_SDK (downloaded from mozilla.org for mac os).

The plugin works as expected by using WEBKIT_DARWIN_SDK but since it conflicts with my other libraries I can't use it. Now the only way left is to use XULRUNNER_SDK but using that results in a crash on NP_Initialize. Since this is the most basic application using NPAPI it is expected to work ( everything is same expect the fact that internal implementation of webkit and xulrunner could be different). 
Am I missing something here?

Pasting initial few lines from the log

```
Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   net.webvm                           0x00000001004f8228 NP_GetEntryPoints + 24
1   net.webvm                           0x00000001004f82b3 NP_Initialize + 67
2   com.apple.WebKit.PluginHost         0x00000001cfb65188 0x1cfb52000 + 78216
3   com.apple.WebKit.PluginHost         0x00000001cfb599e1 0x1cfb52000 + 31201
4   com.apple.WebKit.PluginHost         0x00000001cfb54ad3 0x1cfb52000 + 10963
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff84fe9a49 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 297
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff84fabe76 __CFRunLoopRun +
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try starting from the [npapi-sdk](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/) Mac example, which is both simpler than npsimple and more up to date.